# jQuery animated slider with variable height and Ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs, sequence

I have a series of links on a floating div (so they're always visible).  When a user clicks one, I would like the following to happen in sequence:

1. The page scrolls up to the top (where the ajax container is located)
2. The current content slides out
3. The new content loads (ajax)
4. The new content slides in

**NB: As the content in each ajax file is different, the ajax container will need to expand/contract to fit.**

I would like to do this without jQuery UI, and keep the code as lite as possible.

I've been googling and attempting to do this with callbacks and queue functions all day, but struggle to get it working as intended.  If anyone can please help me understand how to structure these functions to get it working I'd be incredibly grateful.

**I've abstracted my code to show you where I'm at:** http://pastebin.com/xbJKPmnw

It currently slides the top of the page, and loads the content.  But i'm yet to get the transitions working smoothly and in sequence.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it was never meant to (it can't because it's referencing ajax files that are currently local, not live). I've replaced the jsfiddle link with some straight code at pastebin to ease the confusion.

Comment: Hi there, I've basically got everything already working (each individual function - as referenced in the pastebin).  Was simply looking for a way to sequence each function/animation so that they happen consecutively. I'm trying to keep the code lite as there's already a lot going on in the page (ajax, jq isotope, jq validate, and a bunch of responsive js too)

Comment: have you managed to solve your problem?

Comment: I have thank you.  Your help has been tremendous.  I was acutually able to make both responses work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you've got everything (body scroll, ajax fetch content) sorted out except for the transition itself.

Here is my prototype that does what you need:

1. Makes the old content slide out
2. Makes the new content slide in
3. Resizes dynamic content container to fit new content

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dipish/vhd8e/

The code is quite hackish but delivers the main ideas of the suggested approach. I use the "rel" attribute of links to refer to static mock content. In real life you would make your ajax request, fetch data and then launch the transision.

Sample html:

```
<div id="primarynav">
              <ul id="navigation">
                  <li><a href="page1.html" class="selected" rel="content1">Page 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="page2.html" rel="content2">Page 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="page3.html" rel="content3">Page 3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

<div id="ajax-content"></div>

<div class="preload">
    <div id="content1">I have a series of links on a floating div (so they're always visible). When a user clicks one, I would like the following to happen in sequence:

The page scrolls up to the top (where the ajax container is located)
The current content slides out
The new content loads (ajax)
The new content slides in
NB: As the content in each ajax file is different, the ajax container will need to expand/contract to fit.

I would like to do this without jQuery UI, and keep the code as lite as possible.

I've been googling and attempting to do this with callbacks and queue functions all day, but struggle to get it working as intended. If anyone can please help me understand how to structure these functions to get it working I'd be incredibly grateful.

I've abstracted my code to show you where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/Cz5kg/1/

It currently slides the top of the page, and loads the content. But i'm yet to get the transitions working smoothly and in sequence.

Many thanks in advance.</div>

    <div id="content2">I'm writing a simple javascript to calculate the time difference between server and user time. But something is going wrong.

If I catch the javascript and php date i have:

date("M d Y h:i:s A")
php date : Wed Jun 27 2012 04:10:41 AM  

new Date()
J S date : Wed Jun 27 2012 10:10:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)   
This is correct! I have two different time for local and server time.

Now if I take the seconds time... something goes wrong:

(php: date("U"))
sec PHP: 1340784640    

(js new Date().getTime()/1000 )
sec J S: 1340784640
I got the same time!

Can you help me to fix it ?

Thanks!
    </div>

    <div id="content3">I've been given a big project by a big client and I've been working on it for 2 months now. I'm getting closer and closer to a solution but it's just so insanely complex that I can't quite get there, and so I need ideas.

The project is quite simple: There is a 1mil+ database of lat/lng coordinates with lots of additional data for each record. A user will visit a page and enter some search terms which will filter out quite a lot of the records. All of the records that match the filter are displayed (often clustered) on a Google Maps.

The problem with this is that the client demands it's fast, lean, and low-bandwidth. Hence, I'm stuck. What I'm currently doing is: Present the first clusters, and when they hover over a cluster, begin loading in the data for that clusters children.

However, I've upped it to 30,000 of the millions of listings and it's starting to drag a little. I've made as many optimizations that I possibly can. When the filter is changed, I AJAX a query to the DB and return all the ID's of the matches, then update the map to reflect this.

So, optimization is not an option. I need an entirely new conceptual model for this. Any input at all would be highly appreciated, as this is an incredibly complex project of which I can't find anything in history even remotely close to it- I even looked at MMORPG's which have a lot of similar problems, and I have made a few, but the concept of having a million players in one room is still something MMORPG makers cringe at.

I'll be awarding 500 rep as soon as it becomes available for anything that solves this.

Thanks- Daniel.        
    </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS (mostly left unchanged):

```
ul li { float: left;margin: 0 15px 0 0; }

#ajax-content { 
    width:500px; /* fixed width just for viewing convenience */
    clear:both; 
    border: solid 1px black; /* border just for debugging purposes */
    position: relative; /* to contain absolutely positioned children */
    height: 100px; /* initial height */
}

.preload { /* for test purposes */
    display: none;
}

.item-container {/* style your inner content*/}
```

And finally your modified JavaScript with lots of comments:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $navlinks = $('#navigation li a'),
        $ajaxcontent = $('#ajax-content'),
        animDur = 5000, // animation duration
        isTransitionRunning = false;

    $navlinks.click(function(e) {        
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
        // block actions until current transition finishes
        if(isTransitionRunning) {
            return false;
        }                
        var contentWidth = $ajaxcontent.width(),
            newContent = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).html(), // mock content                
            $newItem = $(document.createElement('div')), // nested container for new content
            newItemHeight,
            newContentHeight,
            $oldItem = $ajaxcontent.children('.item-container');

        // set the flag indicating that the transition is running
        isTransitionRunning = true;

        $newItem.addClass('item-container');

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');              

        //$ajaxcontent.empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='http://expression.ws/stackoverflow/load.gif' alt='Loading Content' /></div>");
        $navlinks.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        /*$.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
            $ajaxcontent.empty().append(html);
            }
        });*/

        // freeze current ajax container height
        $ajaxcontent.height($ajaxcontent.height());
        $ajaxcontent.css('overflow', 'hidden');

        // slide away old item (if any)
        if($oldItem.length) {
            $oldItem
                 // fix width so no wrapping occurs during transision
                .width(contentWidth) 
                // position absolutely
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .animate({
                    left: -contentWidth // move new content at the right edge of container
                },
                animDur,
                function() {
                    // remove old content at the end
                    // you may want to cache it instead
                     $oldItem.remove();
                });
        }

        // append new content to container
        $newItem.html(newContent);
        $ajaxcontent.append($newItem);
        // fix new content width
        $newItem.width(contentWidth);
        // determine height of new content when it's appended to DOM
        newItemHeight = $newItem.height();

        // set up new content
        $newItem
            // move it to the right
            .css('position', 'absolute')
            .css('left', $ajaxcontent.width() + 'px')
            // sliding animation
            .animate({
                left: 0
            }, 
            animDur,
            function() {
                // restore css
                $newItem.css('position', 'static');
                $newItem.css('width', 'auto');
            });

        // change ajax container height
        $ajaxcontent.animate({
            height: newItemHeight
        },
        animDur,
        function() {
            // now let ajax container naturally wrap around its content
            $ajaxcontent.css('height', 'auto');
            $ajaxcontent.css('overflow', 'auto');

            // unset the transition running flag
            isTransitionRunning = false;
        });

        return false;
    });

    //$ajaxcontent.empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='http://expression.ws/stackoverflow/load.gif' alt='Loading Content' /></div>");
    $.ajax({ url: 'page1.html', success: function(html) {
            $ajaxcontent.empty().append(html);
    }
    });
});
```

​

​
It should be clear what's happening there but of course feel free to ask any questions. I'm not a jQuery ninja so some things that I'm doing there might be slightly inefficient but the idea remains unchanged.

The essense of the implementation is:

- **Before** adding new content to your container, fix its dimensions and make it `overflow: hidden;`
- After you insert new content to the DOM you want to measure its height (after having set it to the width of container). This will be the container's target width
- After you made your transitions, remove all CSS that forced position/dimensions restoring the natural element flow (not always necessary but generally recommended);
  ​

**Prototype limitations**:

1. Assumes the content is already fetched via ajax and ready to insert
2. Slides in only one direction
3. Didn't test how this code works if your elements have paddings and margins, you typically need to make some adjustments here because jquery's methods for setting dimensions and positioning elements doesn't always autimagically handle that as you expect it to.

Hope this helps!

**UPD.** 
I added simple logic that blocks execution if a transition is currently running, you can see the differences via edit history here on StackOverflow. Generally this isn't a good approach but it's easy to implement. Implementing a true click-avalanche-resistant widget requires more effort and a better code architecture, let me know if you still want go that way or if you're going to use a 3rd party widget for this.

As for tying this with AJAX data fetching, you should run the transition when the content is already fetched. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
$navlinks.click(function(e) {        
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    // block actions until current transition finishes
    if(isTransitionRunning) {
        return false;
    }  

    // If content is static, you don't want to fetch it everytime,
    // consider implementing some caching mechanism
    $.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
        // this function is basically all the code posted above 
        // except that it takes new html content as parameter
            switchContent(html);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: **+1** for coding a dynamic slider by hand. Bubbling error occurs when clicking a link when the previous animation is not complete. I would consider [**Awkward Showcase – A jQuery Plugin**](http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/) which specializes in dynamic slider height.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed explanation & code - You went above and beyond. Just one or two things... the transitions do seem to overlap when another button is pressed prior when the previous animation is still occuring.  Is there any easy way to fix this?  Also just having a tad difficulty integrating the ajax.  Would you mind adding a quick explanation of the code needed, and how to work it in?  @arttronics - Thanks for the Awkward showcase link.  Looks nice, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work with Ajax content?

Comment: @Nelga, the overlap is called bubbling as is extremely common with jQuery .animate() unless it's dealt with. If I remember correctly, a .stop() is done right before the .animate() to prevent this condition. As far as the Awkward plugin and AJAX, you can configure AJAX to populate content for a Div that Awkward has already established as a content slide. Using Awkward API to advance to that slide can then be done. I'll leave it up to Dmitry Pashkevich to whip something up for Awkward if he chooses, as he has far a better understanding of this workflow than I do.

Comment: @Dmitry Pashkevich, perhaps your willing to create a 2nd Answer, because it's different, that uses Awkward with dynamic content. That plugin seems to be an advanced version of your sure-starter version here but may be just what this SO Question needs. +1 on that new answer from me if you do.

Comment: @arttronics I looked at this Awkward plugin and looks like it doesn't support dynamic content. The plugin code doesn't expose any external functions, it's meant to be run once with the data you already have on the page.

Comment: @Nelga I'll fix the concurrent effects issue in my code and provide guidelines to use it with dynamic content, however it's still only a quick demo illustrating the approach. If you need a quality implementation you should probably find a working jquery plugin for that but you said you don't want to add more external libraries to your page?

Comment: You guys both rock. I don't actually mind adding another external library, but just wanted to ensure that whatever it was is as lite as possible (not bloated like jquery ui).  The Awkward Showcase solution sounds promising, but probably beyond my knowledge.  Ajax is only being used to delay the loading of page heavy page content (loaded only when needed). I'm going to give this revised code a big go right now.  Thanks so much again.

Answer (score 1):

http://explosion-pills.com/11185244.php

This page does what I *think* you're asking (I did no styling whatsoever; I'll leave that up to you).

I think you were pretty close, you just need to change how the elements are queued a bit.  You're also doing a bit more than I think you need to in some spots (`.empty().append` vs. `.html()` for example).

Let me know if I'm off the mark.

Comment: This was very close, but unfortunately when applied to my code, came with the same set of problems I was originally experiencing.  The content loaded prior to the animation occuring.

Comment: @Nelga put the `.load` call in the callback of the `.slideUp` event so it starts after that has completed.

Comment: This code worked just as well as Dmitry's above.  I wish I could award the bounty twice. Thanks so much for your help.